# Help in Set Class

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, set

In this array:

```
[MovimentacaoEquipamento] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [movimentar] => 1
                    [equipamento_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [movimentar] => 1
                    [equipamento_id] => 2
                )
)
```

I need put a **[movimentacao_id] => 45** in each element of array, how do
this with Set Class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out `insert()`.

Untested, but the following should do it...

```
$result = Set::insert($array, 'movimentacao_id', 45);
```